# How to get a sub-directory contents with a different name from another Git repo

Tags: git

Getting a sub-directory from another Git repository with the same name and same relative path is easy, for example:

```
git remote add checklists https://github.com/janosgyerik/software-construction-notes
git fetch checklists
git checkout checklists/master checklists
```

The example remote repository has a directory in its root called `checklists`. The last `checkout` command will grab the contents of that directory and put it in the root of my local repository.

But if I want to put the directory somewhere else? Sure, after the `checkout` I could move the directory anywhere I want with `git mv checklists my/specs/dir/checklists`. However, this could get troublesome if I already have a directory with the same name (and possibly different purpose) in the local project. I would first have to move the directory out of the way. Is there a cleaner way to do this, in one step? Something like this:

```
# grab the "checklists" dir and put its contents to my/specs/dir/checklists
git checkout checklists/master checklists my/specs/dir/checklists
```

Btw, the local repository is a completely independent project. The `software-construction-notes` project is meant as a common resource with a collection of notes, which I just shallow-clone like this in multiple projects to use as a template for doing the requirements analysis and architecture design. These independent projects don't need to track the history of the `software-construction-notes` projects, I really need just the latest snapshot of the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
git read-tree --prefix=my/specs/dir checklists/master
git checkout-index -a
```

might already work.

It reads the checklists/master tree and puts it into the index, but within a certain directory. The checkout command afterwards just updates your working directory from the index and basically reverts the new "to-be-deleted" files within my/specs/dir/checklists.

If you usually agree with what git would do, you can combine both commands via

```
git read-tree -u --prefix=my/specs/dir checklists/master
```